# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token in C

Tags: c, file-io, header-files

I have the following declarations

`FILE *fptr;
FILE *optr;`

in algo.h
 I have the main in main.c which opens these files.
I get the above error if I put the declarations in the header file. If I put it in the main.c, then I get mutiple definition errors like

`src\main.o:main.c:(.bss+0xc88): multiple definition of rcount'
src\new_algo.o:new_algo.c:(.bss+0xc88): first defined here
src\main.o:main.c:(.bss+0xc8c): multiple definition ofcondi'
src\new_algo.o:new_algo.c:(.bss+0xc8c): first defined here`

Comment: Yes, in main.c and new_algo.c

Comment: @Namratha and did you include stdio.h  before of after including algo.h ?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda sounds like you (1) haven't included `<stdio.h>` where you're using `FILE`, and/or (2) have some non-`static` executable code or non-`extern` variable definitions in your headers (and/or are `#include`ing a C file).

The first would typically cause `FILE` not to be defined (or to be `typedef`'d to a type that doesn't exist, in some cases).  The second would cause stuff to be defined in each translation unit that includes the file, which would confuse the linker.

To fix: (1) `#include <stdio.h>` in the file where `FILE` is used, and (2) move shared definitions from the headers into a .c file (and/or declare them as `static` or `extern` as appropriate), and only ever `#include` .h files.

Comment: if you have `void example() { }` in an included file, each .c file that includes it will see (and compile) its own copy of `example`.  (It might inline it here, but for argument's sake assume it won't.)  When it comes link time, the linker needs to see one `example`, or it doesn't know which one to use.  `static` makes the definition essentially private to the translation unit, so each can have its own copy without the linker complaining.  As for global variables, each has to be defined in exactly one translation unit as well -- other translation units should have it declared as `extern`.

Comment: A translation unit is a source file, plus whatever gets `#include`d along the way, minus whatever gets `#ifdef`'d out.  Think of it as the  code for that file after the preprocessor's done its thing.

Comment: Only the main function uses the file pointers. So I don't need new_algo.c to see these. I tried doing declaring it as extern in header and having the FILE *fptr; FILE *optr; in main.c but I still get the multiple definitions error. Why is it not allowed to simply declare these in the header file so that whatever .c file includes the header file can see this?

Comment: If only the main function uses the file pointers, then why are they global anyway?  Just stick them in the function itself and be done with it.

Comment: As for the question, each translation unit gets turned into an object file independently.  And the linker is deliberately simple and kinda lazy.  It basically just sees names, sizes, and contents.  If it sees more than one `foo` defined, it just sees a bunch of things labeled `foo` -- it doesn't know they're references to the same thing, or (in the case of C) even what type they are.  And it's not going to go checking bytes to see if they're "the same thing", cause it can't do that reliably.  So it relies on the programmer and compiler to say "here's my foo, and this other stuff refers to it".

Comment: Do you happen to know what `rcount` and `condi` are?

Answer (score 1):

What you have in algo.h is a *definition* not a declaration. If you have **FILE *fptr; FILE *optr;** in both the source and the header file then you are declaring the variables twice.

You need:

**algo.h**

```
extern FILE *fptr; 
extern FILE *optr;
```

**algo.c**

```
FILE *fptr; 
FILE *optr;
```

Comment: Only the main function uses the file pointers. So I don't need new_algo.c to see these. I tried doing the above, but having the FILE *fptr;  FILE *optr; in main.c but I still get the multiple definitions error. Why is it not allowed to simply declare these in the header file so that whatever .c file includes the header file can see this?

Comment: Your definition goes in a source file (e.g. **FILE *fp;**), this tells the compiler to allocate space for that symbol. Your declaration (e.g. **extern FILE **fp;**) tells the compiler that space for the symbol is already allocated and the linker needs to resolve the symbol. Your error log indicates that **rcount** and **condi** are defined more than once. In any case, don't declare variables in header files (i.e. always use extern).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not including stdio. Add

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

in your header file above those declarations.

Comment: It's mentioned above, that I have. If the header file<stdio.h> be included new_algo.h, I get new multiple defn errors

Answer (score 0):

The linker errors have nothing to do with the `FILE` variables you posted.

There are two variables your source, named `rcount` and `condi`, that according to the linker is defined in both your source files. The reason is, I guess, that you define those variables in a header file that is included in both source files. Some old compilers still can't handle that.